# Make D3 Stacked Bar Chart fill parent SVG container

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a D3 stacked bar chart component and I am trying to make it fill the available space in the parent SVG. This will allow me to resize the chart with HTML rather than having to manually input sizes.

Currently my sizes are hard coded and I have no idea how to change this to a more responsive format.

Here is the relevant component code slice:

```
let data = this.get('data')
    let div = select('body')
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", "stack-tooltip")
    let series = stack()
      .keys(["count1", "count2", "count3"])
      .offset(stackOffsetDiverging)
      (data);

    let svg = select(this.$('svg')[0]),
      margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 30,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 60
      },
      width = +svg.attr("width"),
      height = +svg.attr("height");

    let x = scaleBand()
      .domain(data.map(function(d) {
        return d.label;
      }))
      .rangeRound([margin.left, width - margin.right])
      .padding(0.1);

    let y = scaleLinear()
      .domain([min(series, stackMin), max(series, stackMax)])
      .rangeRound([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

    let z = scaleOrdinal().range(['#DAEAF1', '#99CFE0', '#72BCD4']);

    svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(series)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return z(d.key);
      })
      .selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth)
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.data.label);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d[1]);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]);
      })
      .attr('opacity', d => {
        let selected = this.get('selectedLabel');
        return (selected && d.data.label !== selected) ? '0.5' : '1.0';
      })

  function stackMin(h) {
      return min(h, function(d) {
        return d[0];
      });
    }

    function stackMax(h) {
      return max(h, function(d) {
        return d[1];
      });
    }
```

I did try to change the rangeRound values to a percentage on both the 'X' and 'Y' functions but I was unable to render the bars of the chart when trying to change the values in the X and Y attributes to template literals.

The SVG in the component template is created with a simple `<svg width='800' height="300"></svg>`

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you create fiddle where I can change the code?

Comment: I've not made a fiddle of an ember component before, I'll give it a go!

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I can't get the chart to render in Ember Twiddle and i'm not sure why - I'm still quite new to all of this. You can view the component code here https://ember-twiddle.com/89609d5dcfc82804f894edde703f752b?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2C and I've added some mock data but it might not be much good to you if it won't render! It's worth saying that it does render fine in my application, it's just sized according to defined dimensions

Comment: I've seen some suggestions that removing the "height" and "width" attributes from the `<svg>` element will cause it to fill the parent `<div>` -- hmmm. Not sure I believe that, but it's easy to try. If not, [this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/) has lots of other ways you can try.

Comment: Hi Steve, i think the problem you have is that by default, an SVG without declared dimensions gets drawn as a 300x150 element and it doesn't expand out to its contents as far as I can see. The other problem is that both 'height' and 'width' values are required in the construction of the bars in the chart so I have to retrieve those numbers from somewhere!

Comment: In general, it would be helpful if you provided the version of D3 you are using, but from the looks of it, I would surmise you are using d3js v4?

Comment: Apologies, but yes, D3 version 4 via the ember-d3 add on. I can confirm that individual functions are imported correctly as the chart does render successfully, just not in a responsive manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to scale to its parent container, you'll need to give the SVG a `viewBox`, instead of a `width` and `height`.

The `viewBox` tells the browser which area of the SVG coordinate space, the contents occupy.  That way it knows how to scale the contents.

Comment: This was absolutely the correct answer, thank you. Setting the viewbox actually lets me have a responsive SVG. Unforuntately I still have to declare the width and height in the chart but this is at least something I can work with,